# ModelicaRes import fails in python

Tags: python, modelica, openmodelica, dymola

I want to use ModelicaRes to open my Dymola results in python but the import fails.

`from modelicares.simres import SimRes`

Gives the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [2], line 1
----> 1 from modelicares.simres import SimRes

File C:\ProgramData\Miniforge3\envs\main\lib\site-packages\modelicares\__init__.py:54
     40 __version__ = '0.12.2'
     43 # Standard pylint settings for this project:
     44 # pylint: disable=I0011, C0302, C0325, R0903, R0904, R0912, R0913, R0914, R0915,
     45 # pylint: disable=I0011, W0141, W0142
   (...)
     52 # These will be available directly from modelicares; others must be loaded from
     53 # their submodules.
---> 54 from modelicares.simres import SimRes, SimResList
     55 from modelicares.linres import LinRes, LinResList
     56 from modelicares.util import (add_arrows, add_hlines, add_vlines, ArrowLine,
     57                               closeall, multiglob, figure, load_csv, save,
     58                               saveall, setup_subplots)

File C:\ProgramData\Miniforge3\envs\main\lib\site-packages\modelicares\simres.py:50
     48 from itertools import cycle
     49 from matplotlib import rcParams
---> 50 from matplotlib.cbook import iterable
     51 from matplotlib.pyplot import figlegend
     52 from pandas import DataFrame

ImportError: cannot import name 'iterable' from 'matplotlib.cbook' (C:\ProgramData\Miniforge3\envs\main\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py)
```

I tried DyMat and Buildingspy but I would prefer to use ModelicaRes. Because Buildingspy makes use of DyMat which is quiet old and seems unmaintained.

Comment: You can also use the SDF library to read Dymola result files. See e.g. this blog post for details: https://www.claytex.com/tech-blog/reading-dymola-results-to-python-without-dymola/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had this issue.

I fixed this in my fork of modelicares here: https://github.com/sede-fa/ModelicaRes

I basically replaced any reference to matplotlib.cbook to numpy to get the iterable function as shown here: https://github.com/kdavies4/ModelicaRes/issues/42

You can install this via pip by doing: `pip install git+https://github.com/sede-fa/ModelicaRes.git`